# Denominators of modular symbols

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. For $r\in\mathbb{Q}\cup\{\infty\}$ let us consider the modular symbols of $E$

$$\lambda(r):=2\pi i \int_{i\infty}^{r}f(z)dz\;\in\mathbb{C},$$

where $f$ is the modular form of $E$. By Manin-Drinfeld, we can write
$$\lambda(r)=\left[ r \right]^{+} \Omega^{+} +\left[ r \right]^-\Omega^-$$

where $\Omega^\pm$ are the real and imaginary periods of $E$, and $\left[r\right]^\pm\in\mathbb{Q}$ are the so-called rational parts of the modular symbol.

$\textbf{I am confused by the following:}$

The modular symbols are essentially the modular parametrization $\varphi:X_0(N)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_E$ applied to the cusps (before quotienting by $\Lambda_E$). So, for every rational number $r$, the denominators of $\left[r\right]^\pm$ should be killed by the number

$$D:=2\,\mathrm{lcm}\{ \text{orders of the images of the cusps of $X_0(N)$ in $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_E$}\}$$

(the factor 2 is there just to account for the possible usage of $\Omega^+/2$ depending on whether we have 1 or 2 real components).

Now, let $E$ be the elliptic curve labeled $11.a3$ in the LMFDB:
$$E:y^2+y=x^3-x^2$$

This curve has conductor 11, so it is semistable. Therefore the modular parametrization should map all the cusps of $X_0(11)$ to points of $E(\mathbb{Q})_\mathrm{tors}\subset E\cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_E$. Hence, since $\#E(\mathbb{Q})_\mathrm{tors}=5$, the integer $D$ above should be at most 10.

However, using SageMath we can see that
$$\left[\frac{4}{7}\right]^+=\;-\frac{9}{25},$$
whose denominator is not killed by 10. Isn't this a contradiction?

Maybe I am misinterpreting or forgetting something. What is going wrong with my reasoning?

---

There is even a paper by Christian Wuthrich titled *"Numerical modular symbols for elliptic curves"*, where in proposition 1 he proves that for a semistable $E$ we should have
$$\left[r\right]^+\in
\frac{c_\infty}{2\;\#E(\mathbb{Q})_\mathrm{tors}}\mathbb{Z},$$
where ${c_\infty}$ is the number of real components of $E$. So again, I cannot make sense of the denominator 25 above.

Comment: In your example, the parametrization $\varphi$ has degree $5$. Could that account for the extra $5$ in the denominator?

Comment: More precisely, I think it’s the issue with the Manin constant that makes your example fail (it’s even assumed in the article that we’re taking a case where the Manin constant is one). Look at the LMFDB and pick a different elliptic curve with Manin constant $1$: is the issue still there?

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you! I think you are very on point, the Manin constant seems to be the issue. However, I'm still a bit confused. In the article, I'm under the impression that he assumes the Manin constant of the strong Weil curve $E_0$ to be 1 (he defines $c_0:=c_{E_0}$), but not that of $E$. He states the formula for a generic $E/\mathbb{Q}$. Perhaps this is just a typo and he meant to use the Manin constant of $E$, or forgot to include the Manin constant of $E$ in the last few lines of the proof. It's also possible that I'm still misunderstanding something.

Comment: You’re right that Proposition 1 doesn’t require the curves to be optimal – however, I think that your denominator is not the one given for such non-optimal curves.